# disable signing of LogoutRequest

Tags: c#, wif, saml-2.0

I am currently working on a small ASP.NET project involving authentication of users against a 3rd party identity provider. Currently logins work, logouts don't.

I am using the [WIF SAML 2.0 extension](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/card/archive/2011/05/16/announcing-the-wif-extension-for-saml-2-0-protocol-community-technology-preview.aspx) to handle the SAML protocol.

The 3rd party IdP *does not* require signed LogoutRequests from the service provider. However by default, the WIF SAML extension requires me to sign such requests.

**Question:**

- Is there a way to disable signing of LogoutRequests?

Another library, OpenAM, has an interesting attribute in its [extended service provider metadata](https://wikis.forgerock.org/confluence/display/openam/SAMLv2+IDP+Proxy+Part+2.+Using+an+IDP+Finder+and+LOAs):

```
<Attribute name="wantLogoutRequestSigned">
        <Value>false</Value>
</Attribute>
```

Is there a similar attribute available in WIF?

Any pointers would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, assuming this is SP-Init SLO, and you are using the POST or Redirect binding to send the LogoutRequest to the IDP, the SLO Profile says you *must* digitally sign the Request. See Sect 4.4.3.1, lines 1223-1224:

"The  message MUST be signed if the HTTP POST or Redirect binding is used."

Not sure if WIF will allow you to generate a non-compliant message for SLO or not. I'm guessing that the OpenAM setting is for testing purposes only (or SOAP Binding) and that WIF doesn't have a similar option.

I know I didn't answer your question directly but HTH anyway -
Ian

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I was having problems generating a compliant message, which sparked the question in the first place. Using WIF it seems I have no choice but to sort out those initial problems.